# angularjs set background-image

Tags: angularjs

I have a div to visualize progress.

Therefor I have this ng-style definition:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1)'+bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0+'%,rgba(0,0,0,0)'+(bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%)!important'};"


//output in developer-tools
    <div class="audio-controls-wrapper" ng-style="{'backgroundImage':'linear-    gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1)'+bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?    bufferProgressPercent:0+'%,rgba(0,0,0,0)'+(bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?    bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%)'};">
```

The document only shows the as clear-text. The values don't get rendered.

The values are correct:

```
{{'background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1)'+  (bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%,rgba(0,0,0,0)'+(bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%)'}}
```

Gives this out:

```
background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1)59%,rgba(0,0,0,0)59%)
```

Another attempt was to create a directive:

```
<div class="audio-controls-wrapper" progress-animation="bufferProgressPercent" >
```

Directive:

```
scope.$watch('progressAnimation', function(current, old){
    if(angular.isDefined(current) && current !== old){
      var backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1)'+   (current!=='NaN'?current:0)+'%,rgba(0,0,0,0)'+(current!=='NaN'?  current:0)+'%)!important';
      //scope.$applyAsync(function(){
        //element.css({'backgroundImage':backgroundImage});
        element[0].style.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;

       $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      //});
      console.log(backgroundImage)
      console.log(element[0].style)
    }
  });
```

But the attribute backgroundImage of this element is never set.

Comment: What you expect to ng-style value should be after page render?

Comment: The variables schuld be replaced

Comment: Can you write example what it should looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Did you enter the watch function into directive ?

for example

```
 .directive('progressAnimation', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment         
    scope: { // input the var that you want to watch
            },

    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) { 
 //put your watch function here
          if(angular.isDefined(current) && current !== old){
          var backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1)'+   (current!=='NaN'?current:0)+'%,rgba(0,0,0,0)'+(current!=='NaN'?  current:0)+'%)!important';

         element[0].style.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;

           $compile(element.contents())(scope);

          console.log(backgroundImage)
          console.log(element[0].style)
        }

       } //DOM manipulation
}
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's similar to what I did. Don't forget to inject $compile

Comment: have you debug to check the watch function has entered.

Answer (score 0):

To set the background in I had to use

```
background
```

instead of

```
background-image
```

further I had to replace

```
linear-gradient(...
```

with

```
-moz-linear-gradient(
```

that means

```
{{'background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1)'+  (bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%,rgba(0,0,0,0)'+(bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%)'}}
```

became this:

```
{{'background:-moz-linear-gradient((left, rgba(255,0,0,1)'+  (bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%,rgba(0,0,0,0)'+(bufferProgressPercent!=='NaN'?bufferProgressPercent:0)+'%)'}}
```

I guess I have to add all the browser besides chrom a certain linear gradient.